# Authenticate Jira Api in Java with personal API token

Tags: java, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to retrieve issues from jira. I am able to get response using username and password. But As passwords keeps changing, i want to authenticate using api token. But i am not able to do it.
Here is my Code:

```
public class JiraMetrics {

private static final String JIRA_URL = "https://jira.company.com";
private static final String JIRA_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String JIRA_password = "password";

     public static  void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {




    JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();

    URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
    JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri,JIRA_USERNAME,JIRA_Password);



    //Calling issues
    Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("query");

    for (Issue issue : searchJqlPromise.claim().getIssues()) {
        System.out.println(issue.getKey());
      
    }

   }
```

Instead of password, could we just call using api token?

Comment: is this jira server or jira cloud?

Comment: @luk2302 it is jira server

Comment: In that case you will probably need to go with OAuth: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/oauth/

Answer (score 1):

You have to :

- Generate a token :
  https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/
- Once you have your token, replace "*username*" by your email address and "*password*" by the token.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggested answer but that failed for me.  I did get it to work using the suggestion on this page via an Authentication Handler that passes in the Bearer/Access Token:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-do-I-use-a-personal-access-token-PAT-in-jira-rest-java/qaq-p/1859167